# Change Icon Colors allaround the project in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to change All Icons color in Project. I tried Adding IconTheme in MaterialApp but it does not work. Icons are black no matter what.

```
  static ThemeData light = ThemeData(
    useMaterial3: true,
    colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: lightPrimaryColor),
    fontFamily: "IRANSans",
    iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: lightPrimaryColor),
    elevatedButtonTheme: const ElevatedButtonThemeData(
      style: ButtonStyle(padding: MaterialStatePropertyAll<EdgeInsets>(EdgeInsets.all(16))),
    ),
    inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
      border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16)),
      filled: true,
      fillColor: Colors.white,
      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16, horizontal: 12),
    ),
  );
```